# I/O operation on closed file (Indentation issue) Python-Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, indentation, file-transfer

I have a very basic problem. The client side is perfectly receiving the file and closing the connection. The server side is just having the issue with closing the file and this read(1024) line. Maybe I am placing it in the wrong position. I am confused with the while loops I guess. Please guide me through this. Simple code is pasted below

```
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    input = raw_input("Enter 1 for accessing file and 2 for editting")

    print(repr(input)) # printing input 
    if (input == "1"):
        filename= conn.recv(1024)
        f = open(filename,'rb')
        l = f.read(1024)

    while (1): #Keep sending it until EOF id found
        conn.send(l) #Keep sending the opened file
        print(repr(l)) 
        l = f.read(1024)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop you are closing the file and in the next loop cycle trying to read from it, thus you get the error `I/O operation on closed file`. Apart from the misplaced `f.close()`, your loop is missing a break condition. Better replace

```
        l = f.read(1024)

    while (1): #Keep sending it until EOF id found
        conn.send(l) #Keep sending the opened file
        print(repr(l)) 
        l = f.read(1024)
        f.close()
```

with

```
    for l in iter(lambda: f.read(1024), ''): #Keep sending it until EOF id found
        conn.send(l)                         #Keep sending the opened file
    conn.close()
    f.close()
```